# Docker: Central daemon model is flawed?

Tags: software, architecture, docker

I've read [this article](https://coreos.com/blog/rocket) about CoreOS's new container runtime, rkt, and I'm curious about this section:

> Why not just fork Docker?
>
> From a security and composability perspective, the Docker process
>   model - where everything runs through a central daemon - is
>   fundamentally flawed. To “fix” Docker would essentially mean a rewrite
>   of the project, while inheriting all the baggage of the existing
>   implementation.

As a security newbie, could someone enlighten me about the meaning of this paragraph?

Comment: You have to consider that Docker development ... somewhat deviates ... from the normal open-source model. This is also called "a battle of architects".